# UITableview in ViewController connected to SQLite

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am doing an iPad app.. in which i want to populate the data in UITabelView from database as it is tabelview in UIViewController not UITableViewController, i don't know how to connect them..Kindly help me.!!!!!

find my code for your reference.

```
viewController.h:

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"



@interface ViewController : UIViewController  {
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString * databasePath;
    NSMutableArray *tableOne;
    NSString * string1;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tabelView;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSMutableArray  *tableOne;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tabelView;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSString * string1;

-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase;
-(void)readDataFromDatabase;
@end


#import "ViewController.h"
#import "db.h"


@implementation ViewController
//inserted 
@synthesize tabelView;
@synthesize tableOne, string1;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    databaseName=@"register.db";

    NSArray *documentPaths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readDataFromDatabase];
    [self.tabelView reloadData];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [tableOne count];
    NSLog(@"a");}
// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier=@"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell= nil;
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];}

    db * temp =(db *)[self.tableOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text=temp.name;

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;

}


// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    string1 = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",string1);
}
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success)
        return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}
-(void)readDataFromDatabase{
    sqlite3 *database;
    tableOne=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK){
        const char *sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM employee;";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString  *stringName=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                db *info =[[db alloc]initWithText:stringName ];
                [tableOne addObject:info];
            }            
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setTabelView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
@end


db.h:

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface db : NSObject{
    NSString * name;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

-(id)initWithText:(NSString *)d ;
@end
#import "db.h"


@implementation db

@synthesize name;

-(id)initWithText:(NSString *)d{
    self=[super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.name = d;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: hey,were you give the delegate in .h file bellow this delegate....UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate???

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the tableview datasource and delegate to the view in your nib file in interface builder? You must set those there, or in code, in your viewdidload by setting

```
self.tabelView.datasource = self;
self.tabelView.delegate = self;
```

Also your tableOne mutable array should be initialized only once in your viewDidLoad and when you reload the data from the database you should just remove all array data by using:

```
[tableOne removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: it shows error as: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: you need to set the view outlet to your UIView in your interface builder! Open the nib (.xib) file in interface builder, click on the "File's owner" then click on the outlets (-> arrow) in the right drawer and connect the view outlet to your UIView....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make sure your `UITableView` works before you pull data out of your database file. Simply create a `NSArray` as data source and fill in some data in your `-ViewDidLoad()` and see whether your `UITableView` can pick up. And after you know it works, you can grab the data from database and use the data to populate your table view.

From your code, I didn't see your specify your view controller as `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. I see you implemented those methods but you definitely need to tell your class to inherit  `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.

Even before that, in your interface builder, after you drag a uitableview control to your view, don't forget to right click on it and set the delegate and data source to the file's owner.

Hope this helps.